# ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError

Tags: android, api, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class
```

and this is my gradle build file:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'
compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk')
// compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
//  compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The app works fine with the new version of the API.
But it has the problem with older versions of the API.

Comment: I think linked-in is already having volley library so it is showing duplicate exception.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,The app is installed on the previous version api devices also when i commend out linkedin library from my gradle and linkedin integration code from my program.But how to add the linkedin to my app that suits for older version api devices also

Comment: This question is about Volley. Feel free to create a new post specifically about LinkedIn

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about how to get Volley in your app

```
//  compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
// compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

Those last two are deprecated. The first line is correct.

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

And you need to remove any Volley related files from the libs directory, plus make sure LinkedIn library also isn't using volley

---

I don't see why you need it though when you have Okhttp for http calls and Glide **and** Picasso for image loading

---

Related errors will arise from mixing  `25.3.1`, `23.0.1`, `23.1.1`, and `25.1.1` support libraries. Those all need to be the exact same

Answer (score 0):

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Add above line into your `build.gradle` file in defaultConfig like this:

```
defaultConfig{
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: multiDexEnabled true enabled still shows this error.But it works fine with new version of api.only the problem with old versions,

Comment: That isn't the only step to enable multidex and is an unnecessary way to get around the problem

Answer (score -1):

You can test putting this on root of directory in the Terminal

```
./gradlew clean
```